How to implement a SKE scheme supporting single-message multi-ciphertext using LowMC and GMW?
I currently have a LowMC scheme and a GMW scheme. How can I implement a symmetric encryption scheme that supports single-message multi-ciphertext? In simple terms, I want to implement a protocol like the one described below.
The protocol originates from Figure 6 in the article ZCL22.

LowMC [a family of block ciphers with low multiplicative complexity];
GMW: Oded Goldreich, Silvio Micali, Avi Wigderson: How to Play ANY Mental Game, or A Completeness Theorem for Protocols with Honest Majority. STOC '87

please provide full references, tried to fix it but I am not an expert in this area, so update if needed.
